# R data.table way to set column values from functions & joins without a for loop?

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a way using R data.table to set column values that would require two levels of function calls to set, and is there a way to set column values in a join between two data.tables?

Example: this works but uses a for loop.

```
library(data.table)

# use something from datasets to illusrate
tAmounts<-data.table(rbind(cbind(ID="Apple", Amt=as.numeric(EuStockMarkets[1:50,2])),
                           cbind(ID="Orange", Amt=as.numeric(EuStockMarkets[1:30,3])),
                           cbind(ID="Lemon", Amt=as.numeric(EuStockMarkets[1:60,4]))))
setkey(tAmounts, ID, Amt)

# is there a data.table way to do this without the for loops?

# summary table with the full hierarchical cluster for each ID
tSummary<-tAmounts[, .(.N, Clust=list()), keyby="ID"]
for (Id in unique(tAmounts$ID)) {
  D<-dist(tAmounts[ID==Id]$Amt)
  C<-hclust(D, method="average")
  tSummary[ID==Id]$Clust<-list(C) # any way to mapply & lapply?
}
# ID      N      Clust
# Apple  50 <hclust[7]>
# Lemon  60 <hclust[7]>
# Orange 30 <hclust[7]>
```

Maybe there's a way to say something like `tSummary[, Clust:=hcust(dist(Amt), method="average"), by="ID")` using some combination of lapply and mapply?

Similarly, is there a way to set the column in a join using a function? Continued from example above:

```
# table of hierarchical cluster cuts, e.g., height of $20, height of $40
tCuts<-CJ(ID=unique(tAmounts$ID), Cut=seq(20,100,20))
setkey(tCuts, ID, Cut)
# ID    Cut
# Apple  20
# Apple  40
# ...etc...

# table with clusters taken at each cut
tClust<-tCuts[tAmounts, on="ID", allow.cartesian=TRUE]
setkey(tClust, ID, Cut, Amt)
# ID Cut    Amt
# Apple  20 1587.4
# Apple  20 1630.6
# ...etc...
# Orange 100 1789.5 

# set ClustNum for each ID, cut, and amount
for (i in 1:nrow(tCuts)) {
  Id<-tCuts[i]$ID
  tClust[ID==Id & Cut==tCuts[i]$Cut, ClustNum:=cutree(tSummary[ID==Id]$Clust[[1]], h=tCuts[i]$Cut)] # any way to mapply in a join?
}
```

Is there something like `tClust[tCuts, ClustNum:=cutree(Clust, h=Cut)]` that can join and set the value all at once?

Comment: Try `tSummary2 <- tAmounts[, .(.N, Clust = list(hclust(dist(.SD), method="average"))), .SDcols="Amt", by=ID]`, or using the new `env` interface about to be released  `tSummary3 <- tAmounts[, .(.N, Clust = list(hclust(dist(v), method="average"))), by="ID", env=list(v="Amt")]`

Comment: FYI, never use `cbind` to form a frame; in this case looking at `tAmounts` one can see that `Amt` is a string column, not numeric.

Comment: @Tobo, why the use of `.SD` or the recommendation for `env=`? Doesn't it work using `Amt` directly, as in `tAmounts[, .(N=.N, Clust = list(hclust(dist(Amt), method="average"))), by=ID]`? Also, I suggest you post that as an answer.

Comment: @r2evans Hi and thanks for chiming in. I just bashed the comment out last night before popping to the pub for last orders, and intended to look more closely today, but haven't been able to. I will do that either last thing tonight or tomorrow. That said, what you say looks quite right! Also I think a join in part 2 is unnecessary, as it's the same step per ID.

Comment: @r2evans Solution up, and thanks for the catches. I found this a good learning exercise. A less kludgy way of creating the Cut and Amt columns in Part 2 would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1: Table of counts and `hclust` objects, one for each ID**

The solution here is just to wrap the RHS of the j-expression inside `list()`.

```
tSummary <- 
  tAmounts[, .(.N, Clust = list(hclust(dist(Amt), method="average"))), by="ID"]
```

**2: Clusters at heights 20, 40, ..., 100**

The `ClustNum` column of cluster tags can be created from 1 directly (without the cross-joins and intermediate tables). `by=ID` takes care of the iteration over IDs, while to iterate over heights without looping, we can either use an `apply` function, or use the fact that `cutree()` accepts a vector of heights.

```
cuts <- seq(20,100,20)

# EITHER lapply over heights (and create the Cut column "manually"):
tClust <-
  tSummary[, .(Cut = rep(cuts, each=N),
               ClustNum = unlist(lapply(cuts, function(h) cutree(Clust[[1]], h=h)))),
           by=ID]

# OR pass the vector of heights to cutree():
tClust <-
  tSummary[, melt(as.data.table(cutree(Clust[[1]], h=cuts)),
                  variable.name="Cut", variable.factor=F, value.name="ClustNum"),
           by=ID]

# Add the amounts column
tClust[, Amt := tAmounts[, rep(Amt, times=length(cuts)), by=ID][, ID := NULL]]
```

**Example data** (ensuring `Amt` column numeric):

```
library(data.table)
tAmounts <- rbind(
      data.frame(ID="Apple", Amt=as.numeric(EuStockMarkets[1:50,2])),
      data.frame(ID="Orange", Amt=as.numeric(EuStockMarkets[1:30,3])),
      data.frame(ID="Lemon", Amt=as.numeric(EuStockMarkets[1:60,4]))
    ) |> setDT()
setkey(tAmounts, ID)
```

Thanks to @r2evans for help

Comment: Thanks works: all 700 samples come out the same way, now without for loops--thanks! Answer just needs an edit to change "length(heights)" to "length(cuts)" on the last line. I get an error message when trying to edit it, maybe someone else can try.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for acknowledging and for pointing out that edit.